# Hello. I am new to java and stuck at Linked List reverse problem and don't know how to solve it

Tags: java, linked-list

It's showing some kind to error at head "Cannot resolve symbol 'head' ".

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class reversellusingiteration {
    static Node head;

    static class Node{
        int data;
        Node next;
        Node(int d) {
            this.data = d;
            this.next = null;
        }
    }

    Node reverse(Node node){
        Node curr=node;
        Node prev=null;
        while(curr!=null){
            Node temp=curr.next;
            curr.next=prev;
            prev=curr;
            curr=temp;
        }
        return prev;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedList list=new LinkedList();
        list.head =new Node(90); //here is the problem
        list.head.next=new Node(78);
    }
}
```

Please someone help me with this

Comment: PLease take care of java naming conventions. Class names should start with upper case character

Answer (score 0):

Your class `reversellusingiteration` has two problems. The `static Node head;` should not be `static`. And it is **not** named `LinkedList`. So you need to change

```
LinkedList list=new LinkedList();
```

to

```
reversellusingiteration list = new reversellusingiteration();
```